# CComSafeArray - type mismatch error when filling array passed from C#

Tags: c#, c++, windows, com, safearray

I am trying to pass an array of `UINT32` from a C# client to C++ ATL COM service.

The `IDL` declaration is:

```
[propput, id(1)] HRESULT ThingyData([in] SAFEARRAY(UINT32) newVal);
```

The C# code that calls it is:

```
thingy.ThingyData = new UInt32[] { (UInt32)1 }.ToArray();
```

The C++ implementation is:

```
STDMETHODIMP CThingy::put_ThingyData(SAFEARRAY * newVal)
{
    CComSafeArray<UINT32> sa;   
    sa.CopyFrom(newVal); //fails here

    //... do some other stuff ...

    return S_OK;
}
```

The code fails at `sa.CopyFrom(...)`, returning `E_INVALIDARG`. I debug into the `CopyFrom` function:

```
HRESULT CopyFrom(_In_ const SAFEARRAY *psaSrc)
{
    ATLENSURE_THROW(psaSrc != NULL, E_INVALIDARG);

    VARTYPE vt;
    HRESULT hRes = ::ATL::AtlSafeArrayGetActualVartype(const_cast<LPSAFEARRAY>(psaSrc), &vt);
    ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(hRes);
    ATLENSURE_THROW(vt == GetType(), E_INVALIDARG);

    // ... 
}
```

Where it fails at the second `ATLENSURE_THROW` because `vt == 23 (VT_UINT)` and `GetType()` returns `19 (VT_UI4)`.

My code is running in 32-bit so this should not really be a problem. After more digging I find I can explicitly declare the `CComSafeArray` to use `VT_UINT`:

```
CComSafeArray<UINT32, VT_UINT> sa;
```

This works, surprisingly. But I am not sure if this is the right way to go about things. Would there be issues with portability, or other weird side effects? I think I read somewhere using `VT_UINT` in COM is not recommended. What I would prefer is a way to get C# to send the array with `VT_UI4` type; is that possible?

Thanks a lot. Trying to wrap my head around all this COM stuff.

Comment: Very hard to see how you could get a VT_UINT out of the CLR.  The only plausible scenario I can reverse-engineer from the CLR source is that this started as a UIntPtr[] array.  ToArray() in the snippet is quite weird as well, I suspect the actual code is very different.  Do otherwise keep in mind that using unsigned types in interop code is unusual, there are a lot of runtime environments that could not use your COM server.

Comment: @HansPassant Nope, my code was as written. It wasn't a `UIntPtr` array. I've since discovered if I change the IDL and c++ signatures to `SAFEARRAY(ULONG)` instead of `SAFEARRAY(UINT32)`, it works fine and C# passes a `VT_UI4` safearray. It's a little confusing on what the difference is, any ideas? Thanks